# Клонирование двумерного массива

Tags: c#, массивы, клонирование

Есть следующая задача:
На серверной стороне в памяти хранится двумерный массив размерностью 10 000 на 10 000 элементов. 
Приходит запрос от клиента: необходимо взять матрицу, произвести с ней некоторые манипуляции(удаление некоторых элементов, размерность изменится) и применить к ней фактор, пришедший в клиентском запросе, после чего вернуть результат.

Запросы от множества клиентов должны обрабатываться параллельно, не последовательно, каждый запрос в отдельном потоке. При этом матрица меняет размерность только для конкретного клиента, каждому новому клиенту нужно отдать для расчета матрицу с ее исходной размерностью.

Вопрос в том, как это делать. Использовать CopyTo - дикость для массива такой размерности. Может быть можно каким-либо образом клонировать его, чтобы отдать копию исходного состояния матрицы, не меняя ее саму?

Comment: Ну а как вы хотите клонировать не копируя его? Я думаю, тут разницы нет - вручную пробежаться по ячейкам и скопировать каждую, использовать `Clone` или `CopyTo`

Comment: А когда должна изменённая матрица стать «видимой» другим клиентам? Если никогда, сделайте её иммутабельной и таскайте с собой новый размер и множители.

Comment: Дополните вопрос информацией о том, должна ли изменённая матрица сохраняться для других или этого же клиента, как долго происходит вычисление изменений для одного клиента, с какой скоростью должна система обрабатывать запросы, как много запросов, элементы массива являются типами значений или ссылочные?

Comment: Видимой матрица никогда не станет, но каждому клиенту необходимо рассчитать некий параметр, используя ее самое первое состояние, при этом клон матрицы может меняться только для одного клиента. Влад, а что Вы имеете в виду? По поводу матрицы-valueType,с система обрабатывает очень много запросов, производительность очень важна. Основная операция- произведение клиентской матрицы и большой серверной

Comment: @Sleeeper: Ну заведите структуру данных «исходная матрица + новый размер + множитель», напишите индексатор — и вроде бы всё.

Comment: К сожалению, новый размер узнать заранее невозможно, элементы могут быть удалены, размер варьируется.  Заводить такую структуру под каждого клиента - дорогое удовольствие с точки зрения потребления памяти.